# CS50 Problem Set 1(Cash/Greedy algorithm) getting runtime error: signed integer overflow

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int count = 0;
    float change;
    // prompt the user for input
    do
    {
        change = get_float("Change owed: ");
    }
    while (change <= 0);
    int cents = round(change * 100);
    while (change >= 25)
    {
        cents -= 25;
        count ++;
    }
    while (change >= 10)
    {
        cents -= 10;
        count ++;
    }
    while (change >= 5)
    {
        cents -= 5;
        count ++;
    }
    while (change >= 1)
    {
        cents -= 1;
        count ++;
    }
    printf("%i\n", count);  
}
```

If a delete the "round" function and then replace coins with 0.25 0.10 etc. The program works, but it shows the wrong answer on some inputs.
I can't think of anything. I'm new to programming but I feel like this is really simple it's just my lack of intelligence.

Comment: @r3mainer The problem set suggests that the program should accept only positive numbers(that's why I have the while loop).

Comment: What's the input?

Comment: _"If a delete the "round" function..."_: what does that mean exactly? Don't describe your code but show it. _"but it shows the wrong answer on some inputs"_, which inputs?? Please [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_

Answer (score 1):

Oh my gah. Can I swear here?? I'm so dumb!! The solution was simple! The problem was: I created an integer "cents" which rounds the "change" value. But in every while loop for each cent type I wrote like `(change >= 10)` when it should've been `(cents >= 10)` so the rounding actually happens. Now it works just as intended! Here's the corrected(and a little bit changed) code if somebody need help on this problem set:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float change;

    int count = 0;
    int total;
    // prompt the user for input
    do
    {
        change = get_float("Change owed: ");
    }
    while (change <= 0); // ask the user for only positive numbers

    //rounds the input and stores the value in the variable "total"
    total = round(change * 100);

    //loops for each type of coins
    while (total >= 25)
    {
        total -= 25;
        count ++;
    }
    while (total >= 10)
    {
        total -= 10;
        count ++;
    }
    while (total >= 5)
    {
        total -= 5;
        count ++;
    }
    while (total >= 1)
    {
        total -= 1;
        count ++;
    }
    //prints the converted(to int) and rounded value
    printf("%i\n", count);  
}
```